# Homebrew Can't Install xctool

Tags: ios, homebrew, ios7.1, xctool

What does Homebrew mean to `Check dependencies`? Is this a Xcode5.1/iOS7.1 issue? I already ran through [this link](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting).

```
$ brew install --verbose xctool
==> Downloading https://github.com/facebook/xctool/archive/v0.1.14.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/xctool-0.1.14.tar.gz
==> Verifying xctool-0.1.14.tar.gz checksum
tar xf /Library/Caches/Homebrew/xctool-0.1.14.tar.gz
==> ./scripts/build.sh 'XT_INSTALL_ROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/xctool/0.1.14/libexec'
User defaults from command line:
    IDEBuildLocationStyle = Custom
    IDECustomBuildIntermediatesPath = /private/tmp/xctool-mj8w/xctool-0.1.14/build/./Intermediates
    IDECustomBuildLocationType = Absolute
    IDECustomBuildProductsPath = /private/tmp/xctool-mj8w/xctool-0.1.14/build/./Products

Build settings from command line:
    XT_INSTALL_ROOT = /usr/local/Cellar/xctool/0.1.14/libexec
    XT_IOS_SDK_VERSION_32 = 7.1
    XT_IOS_SDK_VERSION_64 = 7.1
    XT_IOS_SDK_VERSION_EXPANDED_32 = 71000
    XT_IOS_SDK_VERSION_EXPANDED_64 = 71000

=== BUILD TARGET otest-query-ios OF PROJECT otest-query WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=, VALID_ARCHS=).

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
==> Configuration
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
HEAD: a9fc82aea30506eeacbddeb8b53fb85de8acb9d4
CPU: 8-core 64-bit haswell
OS X: 10.9.2-x86_64
Xcode: 5.1
CLT: 5.1.0.0.1.1393561416
X11: N/A
==> ENV
HOMEBREW_CC: clang
HOMEBREW_CXX: clang++
MAKEFLAGS: -j8
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /usr/local
CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH: /usr/include/libxml2:/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR: /usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Library/ENV/pkgconfig/10.9
PATH: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Error: xctool did not build
Logs:
     /Users/Glenn/Library/Logs/Homebrew/xctool/01.libexec'
```

Comment: It's an issue with Xcode 5.1...

Comment: Can't install xctool with xcode command lines update 5.1 (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/27621)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's an upstream issue with xctool & Xcode 5.1. They've fixed it in the xctool repository, but haven't released it yet. You can install xctool from its git head with:

```
brew install -v --HEAD xctool
```